# Pandas - Sorting MultIndex by the Sum of Sizes

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

I have a Pandas DataFrame that represent requests from users to different websites and each entity in the DataFrame is a request.

To simplify the question let it have only 2 columns - `website` and `ip`.

The data looks like:

```
website.com 1.1.1.1
website.com 1.1.1.1
website.com 1.1.1.1
website.com 1.1.1.1
website.com 1.1.1.2

website1.com 1.1.1.1
website1.com 1.1.1.1
website1.com 1.1.1.3
website1.com 1.1.1.3

website2.com 1.1.1.4
```

I want to group this DataFrame so that I can see the websites which got most hits sorted in descending order and inside each of these website see the IPs that visited it, also in descending orded.

My current solution is:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['website', 'IP'])
grouped_df.size()
```

which will give me:

```
website      IP         Size

website.com  1.1.1.1    4
             1.1.1.2    1
website1.com 1.1.1.1    2
             1.1.1.3    2
website2.com 1.1.1.4    1
```

I can sort this grouped DataFrame by size like `grouped_df.size().sort_values(ascending=False)` but this will perform sorting based on the number of requests each user made:

```
website      IP         Size

website.com  1.1.1.1    4    <---- sorted by size (N of requests from IP)
website1.com 1.1.1.1    2
             1.1.1.3    2
website.com  1.1.1.2    1
website2.com 1.1.1.4    1
```

and not by the sum of requests to a specific website:

```
website      IP         Size    Sum

website.com  1.1.1.1    4       5    <---- sorted by sum and sorted by size inside
             1.1.1.2    1
website1.com 1.1.1.1    2       4
             1.1.1.3    2
website2.com 1.1.1.4    1       1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @jpp Added some minimal data examples and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['website', 'IP']).size().to_frame('Size')
df1['Sum'] = df1.groupby(level=0)['Size'].transform('sum')
#alternative solution
#df1['Sum'] = df1.reset_index()['website'].map(df1.sum(level=0).squeeze()).values
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Sum','Size'],ascending=False)

print (df1)
                      Size  Sum
website      IP                
website.com  1.1.1.1     4    5
             1.1.1.2     1    5
website1.com 1.1.1.1     2    4
             1.1.1.3     2    4
website2.com 1.1.1.4     1    1
```

**Explanation**:

1. First aggregate `size` and convert `Series` to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)
2. Create new column `Sum` by grouping by first level with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `sum` or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `sum` by first level
3. Last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. The idea is to create a `totals` column, and then order by this column at the end of your process.

```
res = df.groupby(['website', 'IP']).size().reset_index()

s = df.groupby('website').size()
res['totals'] = res['website'].map(s)

res = res.sort_values('totals', ascending=False)

print(res)

#         website       IP  0  totals
# 0   website.com  1.1.1.1  4       5
# 1   website.com  1.1.1.2  1       5
# 2  website1.com  1.1.1.1  2       4
# 3  website1.com  1.1.1.3  2       4
# 4  website2.com  1.1.1.4  1       1
```